# Cumulative Total by year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

So, I have the following query,

```
WITH yearlist AS 
(   
SELECT (year(getdate())+3) AS years
    UNION ALL
SELECT   y.years - 1 AS years
FROM     yearlist y
WHERE    y.years - 1 >= (YEAR(GETDATE())-10)
 ) 


SELECT 
a.years as [year],
a.CountryName as country,
  ISNULL(sum(b.sales), 0) as total


  FROM(
  SELECT 

distinct years
 ,g.CountryName
    FROM
    yearlist AS A CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
                                        CountryName, salesYear,  ISNULL(sum(sales), 0) as total
                                                        FROM tblSales where
                salesYear BETWEEN (year(getdate())-12) AND (year(getdate()) + 3)                                        

            ,sales
            ,salesYear) g 



    ) a left outer join

                                        (SELECT 
                                        CountryName, salesYear,  ISNULL(sum(sales), 0) as total
                                                        FROM tblSales where
                salesYear BETWEEN (year(getdate())-12) AND (year(getdate()) + 3)                                        

             group by CountryName

            ,salesYear, sales
            ) b ON a.CountryName=b.CountryName and a.years=b.salesYear

group by a.CountryName,years
order by years
```

I am getting the following returned:

```
year        country                                  Total
---------- ---------------------------------------- -------
2009        France                                   0.00
2009        Japan                                    0.00
2009        Norway                                   2.30
2009        Portugal                                 0.00
2009        South Korea                              0.00
2009        Spain                                    0.00
2009        Sweden                                   0.00
2009        United Kingdom                           0.00
2009        United States                            0.00
2010        France                                   0.00
2010        Japan                                    0.00
2010        Norway                                   0.00
2010        Portugal                                 0.00
2010        South Korea                              0.00
2010        Spain                                    0.00
2010        Sweden                                   0.00
2010        United Kingdom                           0.00
2010        United States                            0.00
2011        France                                   0.00
2011        Japan                                    0.00
2011        Norway                                   0.00
2011        Portugal                                 2.00
2011        South Korea                              0.00
2011        Spain                                    0.00
2011        Sweden                                   0.00
2011        United Kingdom                           0.00
2011        United States                            0.00
2012        France                                   0.00
2012        Japan                                    0.01
2012        Norway                                   0.00
2012        Portugal                                 0.00
2012        South Korea                              0.00
2012        Spain                                    0.00
2012        Sweden                                   0.00
2012        United Kingdom                           0.00
2012        United States                            0.00
2013        France                                   0.00
2013        Japan                                    2.00
2013        Norway                                   0.00
2013        Portugal                                 0.00
2013        South Korea                              0.00
2013        Spain                                    0.00
2013        Sweden                                   0.00
2013        United Kingdom                           0.00
2013        United States                            0.00
```

I am trying to achieve a cumulative total for each country, as the years increase. But I cant seem to get it. I've tried this:

```
 sum(sales) over (order by salesYear rows unbounded preceding) as total
```

But that just filled each row with the cumulative total.

The output I desire is as follows:

```
year        country                                  Total
---------- ---------------------------------------- -------
2009        France                                   0.00
2010        France                                   0.00
2011        France                                   0.00
2009        Japan                                    0.00
2010        Japan                                    0.00
2011        Japan                                    0.00
2009        Norway                                   2.30
2010        Norway                                   2.30
2011        Norway                                   2.30
2009        Portugal                                 0.00
2010        Portugal                                 0.00
2011        Portugal                                 2.00
2009        South Korea                              0.00
2010        South Korea                              0.00
2011        South Korea                              0.00
2009        Spain                                    0.00
2010        Spain                                    0.00
2011        Spain                                    0.00
2009        Sweden                                   0.00
2010        Sweden                                   0.00
2011        Sweden                                   0.00
2009        United Kingdom                           0.00
2010        United Kingdom                           0.00
2011        United Kingdom                           0.00
2009        United States                            0.00
2010        United States                            0.00
2011        United States                            0.00
```

I just cant seem to get them to individually accumulate.

Comment: Please show your original data.  Or better yet, also create a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely need a partition by clause, too:

```
sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by country order by salesYear rows unbounded preceding)
```

Comment: You've just absolutely nailed it.